# Making if statements cancel other code. (java)

Tags: java

I am fairly new to programming Java. I want to make a lotto program. Here is the code:
package me.nutella;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lotto {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter A Number Between 1-20!");
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();

            if (choice > 20)
                System.out.print("Please Only Pick Numbers Between 1-20!");

            int b = (int) (Math.random() * 20) +1;
            if (choice == b) 
                System.out.print("You Win!");
            else
                System.out.print("You Lost! The correct answer was " + b);


        }

        catch(Exception E) {
            System.out.print("Your Answer Must Be Numeric!");
        }
    } 
}
```

Now, this part if what I am mainly concerned about:

if (choice > 20)
            System.out.print("Please Only Pick Numbers Between 1-20!");

I want to make it so if someone puts the number over 20, it will print that message. Now this part does work, but when I put the number over 20, it still plays the lotto game. I want to make it so if they put their number higher than 20, it will not play the game and enter that message.
How can this be done?

Comment: Use an `else` statement? (And don't forget to use braces)

Comment: What have you tried, what control structures (like `if`) have you already learnt about in school?
Finally how have you done the win/lost logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be most elegantly done using a `do {...} while();` `loop`. At the beginning, the user must always enter a number, so the `loop` *MUST* execute at least once. This is where a `do {...} while();` `loop` comes in handy. You can display your message at the beginning of the loop, then read in the users input. If it is in an acceptable range, the `loop` never re-executes, and the code moves on. But, if it is not acceptable, we re-execute the `loop` until we get an acceptable value.

Below is how I would approach this problem:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("Please Pick A Number Between 1-20!");
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
    } while(choice > 20 || choice < 1);
```

It is also worth noting that your message states that "Number between 1-20", but your code only checks that `choice < 20`, so if a user enter anything *LESS THAN* 20, it would be accepted. This includes 0, negatives, and of course the valid number range. I added the `|| choice < 1` check in my example.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a loop to keep getting inputs if input is not valid:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter A Number Between 1-20!");
int choice = scanner.nextInt();
boolean validInput=false;
while(!validInput) {
   int choice = scanner.nextInt();
   if (choice > 20) {
      System.out.print("Please Only Pick Numbers Between 1-20!");
   } else {
      validInput=true;
   }
}
int b = (int) (Math.random() * 20) +1;
if (choice == b) 
   System.out.print("You Win!");
else
   System.out.print("You Lost! The correct answer was " + b);
```